# GTM - how to capture click event on button and change it's behavior

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-tag-manager

I've searched a lot, read the docs but all I found on this issue refers to analytics and following, counting clicks only.
But the thing I need to do is to change the behavior of one of the buttons on the website, so that when user clicks on one product card's 'buy' button, the gtm would capture this click and redirect the user to another url instead of adding the product to cart (default behavior).
The reason I need to do it thru gtm and not by changing frontend code directly is the long release cycle of our product (2 weeks), but we need to change button behavior for several days only, check reactions and than cancel it.

Is it possible to do at all with gtm and what should I add there (trigger / tag)? Do I need to write special script for this or is it possible to do by native gtm functions?

Comment: Might need to provide more information like how is the button trigger the function currently. And we can provide some idea based on that. Screenshots and code are better to understand.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter in much details. Currently the button dispatches a redux action to add a product to the cart. I need to intercept this click with google tag manager and make this click to redirect to another page. Yesturday one guy answered me, but for some reason he deleted the answer. It was to drop a trigger on button and add intercepting code to gtm smth like `window.location.href = 'https://test.com'`. Looks like it works...

Comment: If it work then it is fine. Looks like it didn't remove the original event listener and just use winlow location to redirect to another page.